# Untrusted data in php

Tags: php, html, xss

what is the meaning of untrusted data? is it all data that generate dynamically? or just data from user input?

Comment: What's  your problem??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/129677/3794472

Comment: You better start reading this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i'm just confuse what is untrusted data? is it only the output that we generate by php or all script in html like "img src=" is part of untrusted data. i just want to prevent my site from XSS attack.

Comment: XSS and SQL injection is different @salep

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley i'm not asking how to sanitize, i just asking what is untrusted data and what input or output that can be categorized untrusted data.

Comment: @Kyo you just want to prevent from `XSS` attack

Comment: I know how to validate and sanitize but which input i should validate and sanitize is it all including html to display an images?

Comment: @Kyo Anything that you cannot personally verify. This includes all user-supplied input, and any data which you retrieve from other sites that you don't control.

Comment: @lawrenceoverflow i want to know which input or output i should aware from xss and that called untrusted data. but what is categorized untrusted data?

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley but i read at OWASP that:

<script>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</script>   directly in a script
 
 <!--...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...-->             inside an HTML comment
 
 <div ...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...=test />       in an attribute name
 
 <NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE... href="/test" />   in a tag name
 
 <style>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</style>   directly in CSS

so if it only user suplied input that script above should be untrusted data right?

Comment: @Kyo check my answer below it will protect from `XSS` attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the already posted answers and comments to this and similar questions here, the answer to *your* question "what is untrusted data" is simple:

*Everything* coming from the client, regardless whether via POST, GET, PUT, HEAD, Cookie or whatever else should be regarded as untrusted.

As a matter of fact, all data coming from "the client" must not come from there and can always be crafted for abusing any vulnerability of your server software, whether you are using it or not.

Period.

Comment: this is the most clearer answer beside Tivie answer. so if that not from user it categorized as trusted data right? i mean if it's from my script like IMG SRC =MYPIC.JPG?

Answer (score 1):

Untrustworthy data is any data that can potentially harm your web application. Being automatically generated doesn't automatically make data dangerous.

Generally speaking, if the data comes from somewhere or something you don't trust, then it's untrustworthy.

Usually that means any data that comes from the user land.

The way you should secure data is related to what that data will be used for. For instance, if you wish to store it in a database, then you must ensure it is properly escaped to prevent SQL injection.
If the data will be used to exec shell commands, then escapeshellarg and escapeshellcmd is in order.

---

Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in Web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side script into Web pages viewed by other users.

It can happen If your web app displays unescaped data introduced by users. A simple example would be a blog site which doesn't escape comments from users. Removing HTML entities (such as Script tags, Iframes, etc...) should be enough to prevent this kind of attack.

Comment: so it mean all file that static like img src=me.jpg is secure right? since it's not generated by input or output? or is still need to be protected?

Comment: @Kyo **you better first learn about `PHP`** your still confused about input and output, You have to use prepared statements from PDO

Comment: wth, i know input and output, all i want is which input? i know that input is script that we generate to take data from user by a form, and output like echo, printr. it seem only Tivie who know what i mean here.

Comment: like this script <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> is catogorized trusted data or not? is it save or not or we need to filter it? that's what i ask.

Comment: You can inject JavaScript in img src attributes in older browsers.

Comment: All examples you gave are safe. However, if there's a script, object, embed, etc tag somewhere then it is not safe.

Comment: in my case, IMG SRC=myimages.jpg is save right? since it's not from user by from my server file?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use the function like `htmlspecialchars()` to protect from `XSS` and  output something to the browser that came from the user input.**

When you echo your input use it like posted bellow

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

[Google Code University](http://code.google.com/edu/) also has [some very educational videos on Web Security](http://code.google.com/edu/security/index.html#videos).

Comment: so <script>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</script> directly in a script <!--...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...--> inside an HTML comment <div ...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...=test /> in an attribute name <NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE... href="/test" /> in a tag name <style>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</style> is not from static data? it's all from user input and our output print like echo right?

Comment: yes OUTPUT means `echo`

Comment: so <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> is catogorized trusted data or not?

Comment: can you please post your code so that **people who visit your question** can find what problem you have

Comment: please read this so u'll understand what i mean here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: take a look at this code <IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')> so are we need to filter all IMG SRC link or just the link that we take from user?

Comment: @Kyo **Never trust user input** you MUST have certain security for Your site SO use form validator while processing input

Comment: why do you need to allow `<IMG SRC=javascript:alert('XSS')>` these charter in input box

Comment: it's not what i mean here, i mean if i display img then attacker or hacker input that kind of code.

Comment: When You allow user to input data there are many possible ways hacker can attack you

Comment: don't ask me, ask hacker. if they can attack google and facebook why they can't just attack a display images?

Comment: lawrance all you have to do is answer save or not and we can stop argue. i'm the one who confuse here not u.

Comment: Google and facebook have good validator function and they **never trust user input** they have certain filter to validate user input

Comment: yeah i will never trust too, this question is which data i should trust or not. Axel answer is the right one that i want and very clear.